# Создать массив вида serialize() на основе числа

Tags: php, mysql

В общем из базы получаю count число например = 8.
Мне нужно из 8 получить массив.

```
a:8:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:8;}
```

Пробую перебрать при помощи цикла

```
foreach(range(0, 8) as $number)
 {

     $arr = array($number);
     $str = serialize($arr);
     print_r($str);
 }
```

На выходе получаю:

```
a:1:{i:0;i:0;}a:1:{i:0;i:1;}a:1:{i:0;i:2;}a:1:{i:0;i:3;}a:1:{i:0;i:4;}a:1:{i:0;i:5;}a:1:{i:0;i:6;}a:1:{i:0;i:7;}a:1:{i:0;i:8;}
```

А нужно:

```
a:8:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:8;}
```

Comment: Почему вы мой ответ отметили как неверный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$num = 8;
$arr = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i ++)
{
    $arr[] = $i;
}

echo serialize($arr);

a:8:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;i:8;}
```

Comment: вот для этого бог создал метод range() 

`var_dump(serialize(range(1, 8)));`

Comment: Да, результат выполнения аналогичный, но я почему-то всегда мимо нее проходил

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию [range()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.range.php) для создания массива, содержащего диапазон элементов:

```
 $number = 8;
 $arr = range(1, $number);
 $str = serialize($arr);
 print_r($str);
```